# ASTVisitor get variable modifiers

Tags: java, refactoring

hi im using ASTVisitor and im trying to get the modifiers of a variable ive managed to get the modifiers of a method with:

```
    int modifiers = node.getModifiers();

    if (Modifier.isPrivate(modifiers)){
        if (Modifier.isStatic(modifiers)) {
            if (Modifier.isFinal(modifiers)) {
                this.createMarker(node);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.visit(node);
```

but i cant seem to get the modifiers of a variable could someone point me in the right direction

java version 1.7
Eclipse JDT Release 3.8

Comment: ASTVisitor from what specific package?  There's lots of Java parsers out there, in just Java.

Comment: The version of Java that im using is 1.7

Comment: You didn't answer the question.